# DoCmd.OpenQuery or DoCmd.RunSQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Redesigning parts of my employers database I come across subroutines wrote by who ever created it originally that go something like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry1"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry2"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry3"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry4"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry5"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry6"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry7"
etc...
etc.....
etc.......
```

I have always used DoCmd.RunSQL for running queries behind events etc, mainly because the SQL is then all in front of me in one place within the VBA editor.

Currently some procedures have up to 50 OpenQuery dealing with tables with 250000+ records. Having a brief look through the queries it seems that many of them can be combined as they do similar things with the same data sets, it appears to me whoever wrote them didn't have a good understanding of SQL.

My question is which method is better in terms of performance etc. DoCmd.OpenQuery or DoCmd.RunSQL

Comment: Are you opposed to `CurrentDb.Execute "qry1", dbFailOnError` instead of `OpenQuery` or `RunSQL`?

Comment: Not particularly I am just looking for the most efficient method. I like being able to see the SQL within the module I am writing rather than having to switch between the access and vba windows which is why I like to use RunSQL

Comment: If you mean you want to use a SQL statement instead of a query name, `CurrentDb.Execute` will cooperate: `CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM tblFoo;", dbFailOnError`

Comment: Is there an advantage to that over DoCmd.RunSQL?

Comment: Yes, several.  For one, examine what the *Database.Execute Method* help topic says about `dbFailOnError`

Comment: Very useful thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If these are action queries (`UPDATE` or `DELETE` or `INSERT`, rather than just `SELECT`), it really doesn't matter. (There might be some minuscule overhead where Access is trying to collect output records to display in a grid.)

If they are not action queries, then `DoCmd.RunSQL` wouldn't do anything anyhow.

Also, consider using `DoCmd.Execute` rather than `DoCmd.RunSQL`, since Execute can take a saved query name instead of just raw SQL.